# How To determine this user late pay for this week in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

So here I have a case to determine this user he's late or not in his payments every week, to determine the late comparison to the date of payment and the previous overdue field

i have sample data like this

```
Name   to be paid    DATE PAID       OVERDUE DATE
Bakrie  195000       2019-07-01       2019-07-08
Rocky   195000       2019-07-01       2019-07-08
Bakrie  195000       2019-07-15       2019-07-22
Bakrie  195000       2019-07-29       2019-08-05
Bakrie  195000       2019-08-05       2019-08-12
Febri   130000       2019-06-25       2019-07-02
```

data that wish to be generated

```
 Name   to be paid    DATE PAID       OVERDUE DATE    sign
Bakrie  195000       2019-07-01       2019-07-08      NOT LATE
Rocky   195000       2019-07-01       2019-07-08      NOT LATE
Bakrie  195000       2019-07-15       2019-07-22      LATE
Bakrie  195000       2019-07-29       2019-08-05      Late
Bakrie  195000       2019-08-05       2019-08-12      not late
Febri   130000       2019-06-25       2019-07-02     not late
```

as you see ***user name bakrie he late payment because in second payment date paid is passing due date in previous record due date of his payment***

I've tried querying like this but failed. He shows data not late like this

```
Bakrie  195000  2019-07-01  2019-07-08  NOT LATE
Bakrie  195000  2019-07-01  2019-07-08  NOT LATE
Bakrie  195000  2019-07-01  2019-07-08  NOT LATE
Bakrie  195000  2019-07-01  2019-07-08  NOT LATE
Rocky   195000  2019-07-01  2019-07-08  NOT LATE
Bakrie  195000  2019-07-15  2019-07-22  LATE
```

my query like this`

```
  select trackku.*, if(date paid > overdue_paid,'LATE','NOT LATE') from trackku
```

please help me!?!?!

Comment: Why do you want to sign a LATE payment for Bakrie, when he paid on 2019-07-29, and the due date was 2019-08-05?

Comment: The data you get from your query doesn't correspond to your sample data in table. See overdue dates...

Comment: Yeah, but not only will bakrie be when there's another user late to determine that he's late or not.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your explanation. Please clarify in the data and fix your overdue dates.

Comment: Why do you want to sign a LATE payment for Bakrie, when he paid on 2019-07-29, and the due date was 2019-08-05?

because previous record reminder due date is  2019-07-22   and next reocrd he pay in date 2019-07-29 thats why he sign late payment

Comment: as you see user name bakrie he late payment because in second payment date paid is passing due date in first record due date

Comment: This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to the following query based on your description of the problem.

```
select
  a.name, a.paid, a.date_paid, a.overdue_date,
  case
    when max(b.overdue_date) is null or
         max(b.overdue_date) >= a.date_paid then
      'not late'
    else
      'late'
  end as sign
from trackku as a
left join trackku as b
  on a.name = b.name and a.date_paid > b.date_paid
group by a.name, a.paid, a.date_paid, a.overdue_date;
```

**Output:**

```
+--------+--------+------------+--------------+----------+
|  name  |  paid  | date_paid  | overdue_date |   sign   |
+--------+--------+------------+--------------+----------+
| Bakrie | 195000 | 2019-07-01 | 2019-07-08   | not late |
| Bakrie | 195000 | 2019-07-15 | 2019-07-22   | late     |
| Bakrie | 195000 | 2019-07-29 | 2019-08-05   | late     |
| Bakrie | 195000 | 2019-08-05 | 2019-08-12   | not late |
| Febri  | 130000 | 2019-06-25 | 2019-07-02   | not late |
| Rocky  | 195000 | 2019-07-01 | 2019-07-08   | not late |
+--------+--------+------------+--------------+----------+
```

Test it online with [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c8467a/11).

Comment: While I've tried the test to include data to ensure this query is correct and the results are in line with what I asked above, and the results are correct,
Thank you for helping me, sir.,